# How to create slideshow from images with ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, linux, ffmpeg

I want to create a slideshow from images, where each image would be displayed for some period of time (several seconds).

How do I do that?

Currently I was trying to encode short clips with ffmpeg and then stitch those together with `mencoder`:

```
        foreach (var item in filePattern)
        {
            var otpt = item.Key + ".mpg";
            Process.Start("ffmpeg",
                string.Format("-y -r 25 -f image2 -vframes 75 -i {0} {1}", item.Value, otpt)//-loop 1
                ).WaitForExit();
        }
```

`ffmpeg -y -r 25 -f image2 -vframes 75 -i input-pattern output` does create a file with 1 frame in it, while `ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -r 25 -f image2 -vframes 75 -i input-pattern output` on windows never finishes (needs ctrl+c to stop); the second command worked on linux for me.

I need to make this work primary on Windows. Which params should I use?

Comment: I already did this with mencoder, trying several codecs. I can tell you from experience that most video players (all I've tried out) are **very very bad** at handling low-fps movies. For example, `mplayer` responds only every three frames to interactive input, while `vlc` simply would refuse to play the file unless I changed its framerate to something like 10fps or so. Bottom line, I'd rather suggest you stay with your images and look for an image viewer with scripting capability (or command-line slideshow)

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=ffmpeg%20slideshow&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=4fc1c984211b8d1b&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1680&bih=925).

But as Jo So said, many players have issues playing back low fps files.  Depending on the player you're going to be using, you'll have different answers on how to solve this.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  Having a similar problem trying to create a 'slideshow' (low framerate video) from still images using ffmpeg.  No joy yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add -t 3:

-y -r 25 -f image2 -vframes 75 -i {0} -t 3 {1}